# How to use actionValidateCustomerAddressForm hook to get the address of customer

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules, prestashop-helper-classes

How to use `actionValidateCustomerAddressForm`, during runtime of address update details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `actionValidateCustomerAddressForm` you will get the whole address form as parameter.

```
public function hookActionValidateCustomerAddressForm($params){
   $addressForm = $params['form'];
   // do the stuff
}
```

Of course, you can use the hook only in a module. For generating a basic custom module, check the https://validator.prestashop.com/